# JQuery icon does not render in IE9

Tags: jquery

I have a cancel button defined as follow:

```
<td>
    <br />
    <a id="btnClear" class="custom_dialog_link ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-cancel"></span>Clear </a>
    <br />
</td>

<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-cancel"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-cancel"></span></li>
```

In IE9 it rendered as below. I tried on FF… the same.

[image]

If I set compatibility mode, it rendered correctly as below:

[image]

I googled the problem, someone recommended add style="display:inline-block". I tried, it rendered as

[image]

But in compatibility mode, it basically shows nothing.

[image]

Does anyone know what is going on here? I would like the button is rendered as the second one, in regular or compatibility mode. Is it possible?

Comment: You should seriously consider cropping those images...

Answer (score 0):

Try using css [min-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp) in an IE stylesheet for the button.